# Can you change the Visual Studio resource editor background color?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I like using the Dark theme in Visual Studio but one of the elements unaffected by this change is the Resource Editor background color. It punches me in the face each time I have to open the darn thing.

I cannot see this element listed in the standard Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors nor can I see it listed in the [Visual Studio 2015 Color Theme Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2015ColorThemeEditor).

Any other ideas?

Thanks.